# PHP: Sort Array Keys Descending and Alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Greetings Stackoverflow.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
[D35D] => D35D
[D35C] => D35C
[D14D] => D14D
[D14B] => D14B
[D14A] => D14A
[D13C] => D13C
```

Is there a way to sort the array by key and keeping the sorting descending but alphabetically? So the **result array** will be like this:

```
[D35C] => D35C
[D35D] => D35D
[D14A] => D14A
[D14B] => D14B
[D14C] => D14C
[D13C] => D13C
```

Comment: I also want to know!!!

Comment: Please define what you mean by "descending but alphabetically" exactly. Doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You probably want some `usort`/`uksort` function which takes your string apart and compares the numbers and trailing character separately…?

Comment: i think u dont have a unique key in first array to make the sort plz update it with the correct example to understand what you want

Comment: @deceze its only for the last 3 chars in the keys, eg D35D and 35C. 
D
That should be D35C and D35D

Comment: @HamzaNig 

Take a look at the first array and then the result array. 

It should sort by the keys. 

EG in the first array key D35D comes before D35C. 

I want D35C to appear before D35D

Comment: @deceze why you marked the question as duplicate , i have an working answer now i cant post my answer

Comment: @AndreasTherkildsen sorry i have the answer but i cant posting because of the duplicate mark you can start a new question if you want the answer

Comment: @HamzaNig could you send it to me via mail? I will provide you with the email.

Comment: @AndreasTherkildsen ok sure , but i dont have ur email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184748/discussion-between-hamzanig-and-andreas-therkildsen).